# How can I see the content of a file in the staging area in GIT?

Tags: git

I want to see content of a file in staging area not difference of that related to the last commit.
How can I do that?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
git show :that/file   # note the leading `:`
```

[Docs for that revison syntax](https://git-scm.com/docs/gitrevisions#Documentation/gitrevisions.txt-emltngtltpathgtemegem0READMEememREADMEem).

Answer (score 1):

One way is to do `git stash --keep-index`. Now your local file will be identical to what is staged in the index. To get your other changes back from the stash do `git stash pop` or `git stash apply`.